# Image Thumbnail not showing in Magento 2.1 admin panel

Tags: magento2, catalog, image-upload, thumbnail, image-preview

Im working on a custom module in **magento 2.1** which has category attribute to upload thumbnail image from Dashboard>Products>Categories . When i try to upload an image, the preview is shown and the image is uploaded to tmp folder without errors but after saving the image for a category , the thumbnail is not shown in the page. Here is the controller for uploading the image.

```
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $baseTmpPath;
    protected $imageUploader;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
    public function execute() {

        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('thumbnail');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

How can i bring preview of the images Ive uploaded in each category?